# Swift 4.0 No such module 'libxmlKanna'?

Tags: swift4

[image: github:tid-kijyun/Kanna]

https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna

I use Manual Installation

Ive tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you added libxmlKanna to your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same problem, but I followed the instructions given here:

https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna#manual-installation

And it works for me!

I am on Xcode 9.4.1. My project uses swift 4.1.
Make sure you give proper path

> $(SRCROOT)/Modules

in the target Build settings to the Swift Compiler - Search Paths > Import Paths field.

Once this is done, remove the following import statement from your file:

> import Kanna

Answer (score 1):

From the github link you shared, it seems the easiest way is to add `pod 'Kanna'` to your podfile, run `pod install` in your terminal, build your project `cmd + b` and then add `import Kanna` in your project. You said `import libxmlKanna` ?? Just try import `Kanna`